# How select a custom cell in tableview and push to "detail view"?

Tags: ios5, tableview, cell

Got a custom cell filled w some dynamic data in a tableview and that works fine. The problem is that when selecting a cell, **it don't push into the next "detail view"** any more, as it did before I started using a custom cell.

I used InterfaceBuilder, to connect the custom cell in the tableview to the "detailview". (Also tried to delete the old segue and added a new one, but no difference).

Do I need to create a special layer in the custom cell to be "selected" or similar? And/or  can't I use InterFacebuidler to connect the custom cell?

Any tips / pointers? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!**
In the “tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:” method simply call connected segue (created in IB) to perform move to the the connected view (aslo created in IB). This works great, enjoy!;

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SEGcontest" sender:self];
```

*P.s. Thank’s to Jack Nutting, found the solution in your book Beginning iOS 5 Development…”*